# Need help to create Docker container in Go workspace (multi-modular) mode

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, multi-module

I need help, I'm working in the go workspace and there are multiple projects in the workspaces using the common functionality. So, What I did is to make a separate module that contains all the common functionalities that are used by the other modules.

All modules can share their code as we are using the go workspace.

**The file structure is as follows:**

```
Workspace
│
├── Project1
│      ├── main.go
│      ├── docker-compose.yml
│      ├── Dockerfile
│      └── go.mod
│
├── Project2
│      ├── main.go
│      ├── docker-compose.yml
│      ├── Dockerfile
│      └── go.mod
│
├── Common
│      ├── functionality.go
│      └── go.mod
│
└── go.work
```

Project1 and Project2 use the functionalities that are in the `common/functionality.go` by importing them into the project.

when I run the `docker-compose up -d` command in `project1` It says the common module that you import in the project is not in the GOROOT.
because here docker only containerizes the files that are in the directory `Project1`

How can I dockerize separately `Project1` and `Project2` ???

Answer (score 3):

To compile your application the compiler requires all imported packages. When you build a docker image the [`context`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage) determines what files are available; in your case this will be `Project1` (for example). This means that when you run `go build` in your `Dockerfile` the only files available are those in the `Project1` folder. The compiler will check for a workspace file but will not find one (because it's not in the context).

You can work around this by changing the `context` such that it includes the full workspace e.g. `Project1/docker-compose.yml`:

```
project1:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: Project1/dockerfile
    environment:
      ....
```

(you will need to update your `Dockerfile` as well because you will be copying in subdirectories etc).

However the above is not really ideal (it somewhat defeats the point of putting the projects in separate folders). Depending upon your release process a better option might be to check everything in (e.g. to a Git repo), do a `go get -u` (to update the `go.mod`), and then build the docker image (allowing go to retrieve the dependencies from the repo).